# Python for Windows hang while calling a function of MinGW-w64 compiled library

Tags: python, c, mingw, ctypes, msys

I'm using ctypes to call a function of a MinGW-w64 compiled library.

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int hello()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 233;
}
```

Python Code:

```
from ctypes import *
lib = CDLL("a.dll")
hello = lib.hello
hello.restype = c_int
hello()
```

Compile C code with gcc in MinGW-w64:

```
gcc tdll.c -shared -o a.dll
```

Then run python code in Python for Windows 3.5.2, python hangs on **hello()** with 100% cpu usage.
Then I've tried running the python code in Python for MinGW 3.4.3(installed from msys2 repo), it's no problem.

So What's wrong with my code? How can I workaround it?

Comment: What happens if you remove the printf call?

Comment: @2501 : it returns 233 normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc' or 'i686-w64-mingw32-gcc' instead of 'gcc' in msys!

The 'gcc' command calls x86_64-pc-msys-gcc.

Comment: When you are in MINGW32 or MINGW64 shell the 'gcc' command will call 'i686-w64-mingw32-gcc' or 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc'.
Of course it must be installed first.